# Segmentation Fault char** after malloc

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault

I want `** char finalString`, i.e. a list of `*char`. After my function runs, each `*char` pointer contains a `char` 'A', 'B', 'C', which can then be passed to a function expecting a parameter of type `char**`. Each string has to be separate, but in the same array, hence the `**`.

Creating this `**char`, I wrote the following:

```
char ** finalString;
finalString = malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);
int stringAddressCounter = 0;
```

Then, to add a char to this, I tried the following:

```
char ** nextStringAddress = finalString + stringAddressCounter;
** nextStringAddress = 'A';
stringAddressCounter++;
```

However, I'm getting a segmentation fault on the second line of this block.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surprised that you don't get a compilation error with 'Aa'..  There may be less painful ways of doing this - what do you wish to achieve?

Comment: Be aware, 'Aa' is int, not char. One char is just 'A', or 'a', etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocated memory for your `char*` , but did not allocate memory for your `char` to be stored.

Here's a thumb rule for pointer, each * should have a malloc that means for `char **` you should have one malloc for `char *` and another one for `char`.

also playing with pointer is a bit misleading sometimes and bracket should be used instead for readability

```
char ** nextStringAddress = finalString + stringAddressCounter;
nextStringAddress[stringAddressCounter] = malloc(sizeof **nextStringAddress * 3)
nextStringAddress[stringAddressCounter][0] = 'A';
nextStringAddress[stringAddressCounter][1] = 'a';
nextStringAddress[stringAddressCounter][2] = '\0';
stringAddressCounter++;
```

Doing with a single malloc is also possible like so

```
char ** nextStringAddress = finalString + stringAddressCounter;
nextStringAddress[stringAddressCounter] = "Aa";
stringAddressCounter++;
```

Notice the double quote here around the `Aa` and the missing second bracket.
It should be noted that by doing this, you are essentially assigning a memory zone that is read only, and by trying to assign on this memory, it will result in a segmentation fault.